# ¿Cómo se puede formar un vector mediante los elementos de otros dos vectores en R?

Tags: r

Deseo crear un vector, iniciando con los primeros elementos de dos vectores hasta **n** elementos.

Sería algo así:

> A <- c(11, 20, 30, 40,...n)
>
> B <- c(1, 2, 3, 4,...n)

Vector deseado

> V <- c(11, 1, 20, 2, 30, 3, 40, 4,...n, n)

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo que lo que buscas es combinar dos vectores, intercalando en orden cada elemento. Una forma muy simple es usando la función [`rbind`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/plyr/versions/1.8.4/topics/rbind.fill):

```
A <- c(11, 20, 30, 40)
B <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
c(rbind(A, B))
> [1] 11  1 20  2 30  3 40  4
```

Esto tiene un único problema, tal como aclara @mpaladino, que con vectores de tamaños distintos se reciclan valores del vector mayor, además de emitirse un "Warning", un ejemplo sería:

```
A <- c(11, 20, 30, 40, 50)
B <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
c(rbind(A, B))
> [1] 11  1 20  2 30  3 40  4 50  1
```

Para vectores de distinto tamaño, hay una excelente respuesta en [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25961897/how-to-merge-2-vectors-alternating-indexes)

```
c(A, B)[order(c(seq_along(A)*2 - 1, seq_along(B)*2))]
```

Esta solución es muy elegante y sencilla y contempla mas posibilidades que la primera, por ejemplo longitudes distintas de vectores e incluso alguno de los vectores vacíos. Veamos que se está haciendo:

- `c(A, B)`, nada raro, combina los dos vectores uno detrás del otro es decir `[1] 11 20 30 40  1  2  3  4`
- `c(seq_along(A)*2 - 1, seq_along(B)*2)` genera el orden que le vamos a dar a los elementos haciendo que el primer vector se ordene en posiciones impares y el segundo en pares, es decir: `[1] 1 3 5 7 2 4 6 8`
- Por último se aplica el `order` sobre el vector inicial `c(A, B)` y reordenamos los elemento tal como plantea tu pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

La solución de Patricio es correcta. Agrego una precisión, no es que no funcione con vectores de distinto largo, en realidad hace lo que R hace en esos casos: recicla el vector más corto.

Si los vectores no tienen largo multiplo pasa un Warning de rbind (pero no un error). Si son múltiplos ni siquiera pasa un Warning.

Con número y letras para hacerlo más claro.

```
# No pasa un Warning    
A <- c(1,2,3)
B <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f")
c(rbind(A,B))

# Pasa un Warning
A <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
B <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f")
c(rbind(A,B))
```

PD: es un comentario, no una respuesta, pero no tengo reputación para comentar.

Comment: Se agradece la aclaración, efectivamente se van reciclando los elementos del vector mayor, por lo que planteaba @liberal141 me imaginé que no le serviría. Edito la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

No solo didácticamente sino por conocer formas de resolver, además de cbind, puedes hacerlo con una solución nativa en R.

```
A <- c(11, 20, 30, 40,50)
B <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)


vector=list()
indices = seq(1,min(c(length(A),length(B))),1)
for (i in indices){
  vector[[length(vector)+1]] <- A[i]
  vector[[length(vector)+1]] <- B[i]
}

vector = unlist(vector)

vector
[1] 11  1 20  2 30  3 40  4
```

Esta solución no tiene el problema de cbind, si tienen la misma longuitud da tu misma solución, y si tienen diferente longuitud, para la iteración en la mínima longuitud de los dos vectores a combinar.